# SQL query to sum values based on conditions and give flags on the resultant sum

Tags: sql

I need help getting a desired result returned.

example Table1.

| IDNUMBER | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| V11652 | 1500 |
| V11652 | 3000 |
| V11652 | 4500 |
| V11652 | 6000 |
| V11643 | 1500 |
| V11643 | 3000 |
| V10884 | 0 |
| V11645 | 0 |
| V10978 | 0 |
| V10978 | -9000 |

Result needed: to sum up all amount for a given **IDNUMBER**, for any given **IDNUMBER** if any **Amount** is negative then : keep it as is as well as other **Amount** of the same **IDNUMBER**

if the result is >=0 then give flag as 2 else 1

Desired result table.

| IDNUMBER | Sum_result | Flag_in |
| --- | --- | --- |
| V11652 | 15000 | 2 |
| V11643 | 4500 | 2 |
| V10884 | 0 | 2 |
| V11645 | 0 | 2 |
| V10978 | 0 | 2 |
| V10978 | -9000 | 1 |

Query tried :

```
SELECT IDNUMBER,
CASE
    WHEN MIN(CAST(Amount AS DECIMAL(9,2))) < 0 THEN MIN(CAST(Amount AS DECIMAL(9,2)))
     ELSE CAST(SUM(CAST(Amount AS DECIMAL(9,2))) AS DECIMAL(9,2))
    END AS Sum_Result,
    CASE
      WHEN MIN(CAST(Amount AS DECIMAL(9,2))) < 0 THEN 1
      ELSE 2
    END AS "FLAG_In"
FROM Table1
GROUP BY IDNUMBER;
```

*Note* - I have used it as decimal as I need it for calculation, I am not able to sum up values having positive amount and if any IDNUMBER's Amount is negative then keep all occurrence of its values as is.

Comment: [tag:mysql] <> [tag:sql-server]

Comment: Can you have multiple negative amounts per ID? And what should happen with them?

Comment: if there any negative amount, even if a single one then all its amount should be displayed as is (negative as well as positive), rest all can be summed.
so basically all positive amount summed for 1 ID and if the amount is negative then leave that ID as is even its positive amount

Comment: What is your database and version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` combined with `CASE WHEN` clause to separate records with positive or negative amounts :

```
SELECT IDNUMBER, SUM(Amount) Sum_result, CASE WHEN Amount < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS Flag_in
FROM Table1
GROUP BY IDNUMBER, CASE WHEN Amount < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
ORDER BY Sum_result DESC;
```

Result :

```
IDNUMBER    Sum_result  Flag_in
V11652      15000       2
V11643      4500        2
V11645      0           2
V10884      0           2
V10978      0           2
V10978      -9000       1
```

[Demo on sql server](https://dbfiddle.uk/ahPrP3z8)

Comment: This works - thank you so much ! , as I am a newbie to sql could you be kind to explain this query, if you it isn't too much of a trouble

Comment: `This works` ... this answer _fails_ if there happens to be two or more negative amount records for a single `IDNUMBER`.  But it coincidentally happens to work with your sample data.

Answer (score 2):

One approach, using a union to handle the all positive and negative requirements:

```sql
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT IDNUMBER, SUM(Amount) AS Sum_result, 2 AS Flag_in
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY IDNUMBER
    HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Amount < 0 THEN 1 END) = 0
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT IDNUMBER, Amount, CASE WHEN Amount >= 0 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END AS Flag_in,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN Amount < 0 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY IDNUMBER) cnt
    FROM Table1
)

SELECT IDNUMBER, Sum_result, Flag_in
FROM cte1
UNION ALL
SELECT IDNUMBER, Amount, Flag_in
FROM cte2
WHERE cnt > 0
ORDER BY IDNUMBER;
```

The first CTE does a simple aggregation, but only for those `IDNUMBER` groups which have no records with negative amounts.  The second CTE retains all records but creates a flag/count to detect if an `IDNUMBER` group has a record with a negative amount.  We then use a union to bring all records together.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,  your solution worked as well. appreciate you taking this approach and explaining it as well.

Comment: The accepted answer is incorrect.  It aggregates in all cases.  You _don't_ want to aggregate negative records.

Comment: Yes Sir, you are correct, it works in my case, while your answer is more robust and works fine in editor. it couldn't work for me on flat file and gave me *Exception: SQL_FAILURE java.sql.SQLException: Can't parse SQL query  Error was Encountered " "WITH" *.